# Android can't see one of the buttons

Tags: android, xml, button

in my project I use some buttons (2 buttons) the problem is that I can't see one of the buttons (Settings button) not on the virtual device and not on the real device but in the design mod I can see the button. I  would be happy if some one can help me to fix that.
Thanks.

Xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="aa.po.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="My Tasks"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_todo"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_todo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/add_task"
    android:src="@drawable/addtask"
    android:background="@drawable/addtask"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="102dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/settings"
    android:background="@drawable/settings"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="ButtonClick"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of RelativeLayout use LinearLayout.

Comment: post an image of the layout

Comment: @Vucko sorry but not change anything

Comment: @SaravInfern I add a picture of the layout

Comment: Hard-coding the sizes and margins of your buttons is likely causing the issue...

Answer (score 2):

Please use this below xml code and check if your issue is solved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="aa.po.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="My Tasks"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_todo"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_todo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/add_task"
    android:background="@drawable/addtask"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" <-- if your min sdk is below 17 useandroid:layout_alignParentRight ="true" instead
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/settings"
    android:onClick="ButtonClick"
    android:layout_above="@+id/add_task"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" <-- if your min sdk is below 17 useandroid:layout_alignParentRight ="true" instead
    android:id="@+id/settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in your onCreate() method

```
Button task= (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_task);
Button settings= (Button)findViewById(R.id.settings);

task.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
settings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I am get this error "'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference" but I can't know why

Comment: @kobipopo1 Because findViewById returns null

Comment: @cricket_007 But the question is why this is returns null ?

Comment: @kobipopo1 Typically because you have inflated or setContentView with the wrong XML file, therefore those id values cannot be found, so they return as null

Comment: @cricket_007  you are right , may be this guy is using a wrong xml